# jQuery remove email in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have HTML textarea.

```
<textarea> ... </textarea>
```

I don't want users to enter any email address in the textarea. What is the best approach on this using jQuery? How to remove email entered before submitting the form?

I only need hint and references. Thanks.

Comment: Use a regex that matches e-mails. Depends whether you want to exclude only valid e-mails or anything that looks like an e-mail.

Comment: I'm guessing this is for some kind of middle-man site where you don't want people communicating directly, so the user is against you. If that's the case, how deep do you want to go? The users could type `me [at] example [dot] com` (a typical way to avoid spam when posting on forums) or give an IM handle. Catching everything is near-impossible. Also if you catch this on the client-side, any user with javascript disabled (or some technical know-how) will be able to circumvent it.

Comment: +1 for only needing a hint and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/t9cLT/)

Use a regular expression to match the email addresses, and then replace them with blank strings.

```
$(function() {
    $("textarea").change(function() {
        $(this).val( function(idx, val) {
            return val.replace(/\b(\w)+\@(\w)+\.(\w)+\b/g, "");
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Although a genuine concern, the use of JavaScript here will not give you the result you are expecting. The problem is that you want to remove the email addresses automatically before you are submitting the form. This is not a user friendly approach.

You have to alert the user that he cannot enter a email address in the box and ask him to correct the mistake.

Removing the email address part is **MUCH SAFER DONE IN SERVER Level**. Like from PHP, ASP, JSP etc.

Alert the user of email address like this.

```
$("textarea").change(function() {
    if(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/.test($(this).val())) {
         alert("Entering Email ID's are not allowed.");
    }
});
```

Then remove the email for your Server Application.